# Multiple text refering to same template sheet on separate workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a working code below, however I had to develop it further to be able to recognise multiple keywords that refer to the same template.

The function of the code below is:

1. create a new sheet for each cell in column A
2. the newly created sheet will be a copy of a template from a second workbook called "template workbook"
3. There are 5 template sheets, and the template sheet copied depends on a text criteria in column B next to column A

Originally there was just 1 text (in column B) referring to a specific template.

And since the text in column B is identical to the template sheet name, the code was simplet.

However, now I have multiple texts that refer to the same template.

So I changed the code by adding the additional texts as criteria and directly referring to the template, but its not working anymore.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Summary()

    Dim MasterBook As Workbook
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range

    Set MasterBook = ThisWorkbook
    Set Sht = MasterBook.Worksheets("Sheet")
    Set Rng = Sht.Range("B6:B" & Sht.Cells(Sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)

    Dim TemplateBook As Workbook
    Set TemplateBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="T:\Contracts\Measure Templates.xlsx")

    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Rng
        Select Case cell.Value
            Case "Standard Bathroom Template ", "Standard Kitchen Template ", "Standard Bathroom and Kitchen T ", "Windows only ", "Kitchen & Bathroom & Windows ", "Bathrooms & Windows ", "Kitchen & Windows "
                TemplateBook.Sheets(cell.Value).Copy after:=Sht

Dim CopiedSheet As Worksheet
Set CopiedSheet = ActiveSheet
CopiedSheet.Name = cell.Offset(0, -1)
        End Select
    Next cell
Call SaveAs
End Sub

Sub SaveAs()

    Dim FName           As String
    Dim FPath           As String

    FPath = "T:\Contracts\props"
    FName = Sheets("Sheet").Range("A2").Text
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & FName

End Sub
```

**I changed the Case function to:**

```
Select Case cell.Value
        Case "Standard Bathroom Template ", "(B)", "(SOB)", "(S.O.B)"
        TemplateBook.Sheets("Standard Bathroom Template ").Copy after:=Sht

        Case "Standard Kitchen Template ", "(K)"
        TemplateBook.Sheets("Standard Kitchen Template ").Copy after:=Sht

        Case "Standard Bathroom and Kitchen T ", "(B,K)", "(K,B)"
        TemplateBook.Sheets("Standard Bathroom and Kitchen T ").Copy after:=Sht

        Case "Windows only ", "(W)", "(D)"
        TemplateBook.Sheets("Windows only ").Copy after:=Sht

        Case "Kitchen & Bathroom & Windows ", "(K,B,D)", "(K,B,D,W)", "(K,B,W,D)", "(B,K,D)", "(B,K,D,W)", "(B,K,W,D)"
        TemplateBook.Sheets("Kitchen & Bathroom & Windows").Copy after:=Sht
```

1. However with the new code, it doesn't work anymore. it creates the first sheet labelled with the template name instead of the cell value, and then stops with an error "the name is already taken, try a different one" There is no name duplicates in the list on column A btw.
2. Is there a way to give a message when there is a duplicate in the list?
3. How can I make the newly created tabs to be in the same order as the list in the column. Right now it creates it in reverse order.
4. Finally is it possible to hyperlink the newly created sheets to their respective cells (column A) in the summary sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to `Set CopiedSheet` when copying the template to have the reference for later! ;)

```
Sub Summary()
    Dim MasterBook As Workbook
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range

    Set MasterBook = ThisWorkbook
    Set Sht = MasterBook.Worksheets("Sheet")
    Set Rng = Sht.Range("B6:B" & Sht.Cells(Sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)

    Dim TemplateBook As Workbook
    Set TemplateBook = Workbooks.Open(FileName:="T:\Contracts\Measure Templates.xlsx")
    DoEvents

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim CopiedSheet As Worksheet
    Dim LastSheet As Worksheet

    For Each cell In Rng
        Set LastSheet = MasterBook.Sheets(MasterBook.Sheets.Count)
        Select Case cell.Value
            Case "Standard Bathroom Template ", "(B)", "(SOB)", "(S.O.B)"
                Set CopiedSheet = TemplateBook.Sheets("Standard Bathroom Template ").Copy(After:=LastSheet)

            Case "Standard Kitchen Template ", "(K)"
                Set CopiedSheet = TemplateBook.Sheets("Standard Kitchen Template ").Copy(After:=LastSheet)

            Case "Standard Bathroom and Kitchen T ", "(B,K)", "(K,B)"
                Set CopiedSheet = TemplateBook.Sheets("Standard Bathroom and Kitchen T ").Copy(After:=LastSheet)

            Case "Windows only ", "(W)", "(D)"
                Set CopiedSheet = TemplateBook.Sheets("Windows only ").Copy(After:=LastSheet)

            Case "Kitchen & Bathroom & Windows ", "(K,B,D)", "(K,B,D,W)", "(K,B,W,D)", "(B,K,D)", "(B,K,D,W)", "(B,K,W,D)"
                Set CopiedSheet = TemplateBook.Sheets("Kitchen & Bathroom & Windows").Copy(After:=LastSheet)

            Case Else
                MsgBox "Case not handled!!!" & vbcrlf & cell.address & vbcrlf & cell.value, vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Error"
        End Select
        DoEvents
        CopiedSheet.Name = cell.Offset(0, -1)
        DoEvents
        If InStr(1, CopiedSheet.Name, " ") Then
            Sht.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=cell, Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & CopiedSheet.Name & "'!A1", ScreenTip:=CStr(cell.Value), TextToDisplay:=CStr(cell.Value)
        Else
            Sht.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=cell, Address:="", SubAddress:=CopiedSheet.Name & "!A1", ScreenTip:=CStr(cell.Value), TextToDisplay:=CStr(cell.Value)
        End If
        DoEvents
        Set CopiedSheet = Nothing
    Next cell

    'Call SaveAs
End Sub
```

or using ActiveSheet :

```
Sub Summary()
    Dim MasterBook As Workbook
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range

    Set MasterBook = ThisWorkbook
    Set Sht = MasterBook.Worksheets("Sheet")
    Set Rng = Sht.Range("B6:B" & Sht.Cells(Sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)

    Dim TemplateBook As Workbook
    Set TemplateBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="T:\Contracts\Measure Templates.xlsx")
    DoEvents

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim CopiedSheet As Worksheet
    Dim LastSheet As Worksheet

    For Each cell In Rng
        Set LastSheet = MasterBook.Sheets(MasterBook.Sheets.Count)
        Select Case cell.Value
            Case "Standard Bathroom Template ", "(B)", "(SOB)", "(S.O.B)"
                Call TemplateBook.Sheets("Standard Bathroom Template ").Copy(After:=LastSheet)
                Set CopiedSheet = ActiveSheet

            Case "Standard Kitchen Template ", "(K)"
                Call TemplateBook.Sheets("Standard Kitchen Template ").Copy(After:=LastSheet)
                Set CopiedSheet = ActiveSheet

            Case "Standard Bathroom and Kitchen T ", "(B,K)", "(K,B)"
                Call TemplateBook.Sheets("Standard Bathroom and Kitchen T ").Copy(After:=LastSheet)
                Set CopiedSheet = ActiveSheet

            Case "Windows only ", "(W)", "(D)"
                Call TemplateBook.Sheets("Windows only ").Copy(After:=LastSheet)
                Set CopiedSheet = ActiveSheet

            Case "Kitchen & Bathroom & Windows ", "(K,B,D)", "(K,B,D,W)", "(K,B,W,D)", "(B,K,D)", "(B,K,D,W)", "(B,K,W,D)"
                Call TemplateBook.Sheets("Kitchen & Bathroom & Windows").Copy(After:=LastSheet)
                Set CopiedSheet = ActiveSheet

            Case Else
                MsgBox "Case not handled!!!" & vbcrlf & cell.address & vbcrlf & cell.value, vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Error"
        End Select
        DoEvents
        CopiedSheet.Name = cell.Offset(0, -1)
        DoEvents
        If InStr(1, CopiedSheet.Name, " ") Then
            Sht.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=cell.Offset(0,-1), Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & CopiedSheet.Name & "'!A1", ScreenTip:=CStr(cell.Offset(0,-1).Value), TextToDisplay:=CStr(cell.Offset(0,-1).Value)
        Else
            Sht.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=cell.Offset(0,-1), Address:="", SubAddress:=CopiedSheet.Name & "!A1", ScreenTip:=CStr(cellcell.Offset(0,-1).Value), TextToDisplay:=CStr(cellcell.Offset(0,-1).Value)
        End If
        DoEvents
        Set CopiedSheet = Nothing
    Next cell

    'Call SaveAs
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, but unfortunately I'm getting an error for the hyperlink line: Sht.Hyperlinks.Add cell, , "'" & CopiedSheet.Name & "'!A1"
The error message is: Argument not optional.

Comment: I did the change, I don't get an error anymore, however, now the template doesn't open, and no new sheets are created. the only thing it does is, save it in the destination folder with it renamed to the cell value (which is the second code "SaveAs" called within the first code)

Comment: @kira123 : Strange... Try to place breakpoints inside of the select case to be sure that the code flow is passing inside. Because there is no reason that nothing would happen like this....

Comment: @R2uK I tried several things and still didn't work. I removed "call SaveAs" and removed the hyperlink line Sht.Hyperlinks.Add cell, , "'" & CopiedSheet.Name & "'!A1" .  Now it opens the template and creates 1 new sheet then stops with an error: "Object required" and highlights "Set CopiedSheet = TemplateBook.Sheets...."  The new sheet that was created is labelled after the template name and not the cell name either

Comment: @kira123 : I'm stunned that this doesn't work properly... I've added a few lines, give it a try! And btw, you shouldn't use `SaveAs` as a sub name as this is already taken in VBA, try to change the name of that sub.

Comment: @R2uK  Unfortunately I'm still getting the "argument no optional" error for the hyperlink line. and when I remove it I get the "object require" error for the "set copied..." line

Comment: @kira123 : I added a few things to be even surer about the code, try it! Btw, are you sure that the names of the sheets in the template have a space at the end?

Comment: @R2uK I will give it a go. Yeah I'm 100% sure about the spaces. I double checked it with the original code that worked. double checked the template names as well.

Comment: @R2uK This time the hyperlink line doesn't give any errors. but still get the error for the "Set CopiedSheet = TemplateBook.Sheets("Standard Bathroom Template ").Copy(After:=LastSheet)" It manages to create 1 sheet with this template before stopping and giving the error "Object required"  So I'm pretty sure the space isn't and issue since it managed to recognised and copy once.

Comment: @kira123 : I can't understand why this would work once and not more... I've added a second version using activesheet...

Comment: @R2uK This time it does most of the things. It managed to do about 10 properties with correct template and renames correctly and in the correct order, which is great. and then got the error message "case not handled" which I assumed was because of duplicate names, but there was no duplicate name. the error code on VBA was "Object Variable or With block Variable not set". and another minor issue is that the hyperlinking happened to the cells in column B instead of column A (which is what the sheets are named after). Cheers

Comment: @kira123 : Good! Corrected the hyperlink and added more info in the error message! If you have it, it means that the value in the cell is not handled by the `Select Case` statements, so you'll need to correct either the value or include it in the correct `Case "...` statement!

Comment: @kira123 That's perfect!!!! Thank you very much for sticking with it till the end, much appreciated!!

Comment: @R2uK Another minor question for future. Is it possible to set the code to skip blank cell and go to the next one?

Comment: @kira123 : yup, just add `If cell.Value <> Vbnullstring then` right after the for each and `End if` right before the next! ;)